# Claisen condensation of methyl benzoate and ethyl propionate

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am planning to preform the Claisen condensation between a benzoate ester (methyl benzoate is the only one I can get) and a propionate ester (ethyl propionate is my only option). The idea is to prepare this ketoester:
[image]

Will this work with ethyl instead of methyl propionate?

Comment: If ethyl propionate is your only option, then your product is ethyl ketoester. In the scheme, you have used methyl propionate and got methyl ketoseter. Yes, it work with ethyl esters as well, but there is a possibility to get transesterification.

Comment: What solvent is this in? Run it in MeOH and you will get the methyl ketoester

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't matter what the ester is. Well, my stoichiometry will be a bit off, but I am just hydrolyzing the ester anyway.

Comment: And I will likely be using MeOH.

Comment: The ester is likely to decarboxylate after hydrolysis. Is that your intention?

Comment: It is my intention; I plan to make propiophenone